# Editext Validation for Popup

Tags: android, android-edittext

i'm having popup window.Inside the popup window having `editext`. When clicking `button` on inside the pop up window check the `editext` empty and set error on `editext` while touching on error `editext` is getting this error

```
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41d33850 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

how to solve this?

Comment: without code we can't help

Comment: Is your activity destroyed before the validation runs?

Comment: i added my code in that code while i touch the edittext seterror is getting the above error.

Comment: Add your whole activity class code.

Comment: i have added whole activity class code i was stuck in this long time so kindly give any idea?

Comment: any one tell why downvoted this question? it is serious problem

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Activity` state before showing the `PopupWindow`. Use the code below:

```
if (!isFinishing()) {
   // Do yout stuffs here...
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Reset Password");
    alert.setMessage("Please enter the e-mail address for your account.");
    final EditText email = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    lay.addView(email);
    alert.setView(lay);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
}
```